# Find one record that exists as two records in another vendor database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two vendor databases that have become horribly out-of-sync over the years that I'm trying to correct. A single customer can have multiple `id_numbers`, and these IDs exist in both vendor databases. All of the IDs for a single customer are correctly attached to one customer record in the `Vendor1` database (meaning they belong to the same `customer_code`). The problem, however, is that those same IDs might be split amongst multiple customers in the `Vendor2` database, which is incorrect. I will need to merge those multiple customers together in the `Vendor2` database.

I'm trying to identify which customers are represented as two or more customers in the second vendor database. So far I have joined the two together, but I can't figure out how to find only customers that having two or more distinct `MemberInternalKeys` for the same `customer_code`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select top 10
    c.customer_code,
    i.id_number,
    cc.MemberInternalKey
from Vendor1.dbo.customer_info as c
join Vendor1.dbo.customer_ids as i
  on c.customer_code = i.customer_code
join Vendor2.dbo.Clubcard as cc
  on (i.id_number collate Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS) = cc.ClubCardId
where i.id_code = 'PS'
```

In the example below, I would expect to only get back the last two rows in the table. The first two rows should not be included in the results because they have the same `MemberInternalKey` for both records and belong to the same `customer_code`. The third row should also not be included since there is a 1-1 match between both vendor databases.

```
customer_code | id_number | MemberInternalKey
--------------|-----------|------------------
5549032       | 4000      | 4926877
5549032       | 4001      | 4926877
5031101       | 4007      | 2379218
2831779       | 4029      | 1763760
2831779       | 4062      | 4950922
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions for this logic:

```
select c.*
from (select c.customer_code, i.id_number, cc.MemberInternalKey,
             min(MemberInternalKey) over (partition by customer_code) as minmik,
             max(MemberInternalKey) over (partition by customer_code) as maxmik
      from Vendor1.dbo.customer_info c join
           Vendor1.dbo.customer_ids i
           on c.customer_code = i.customer_code join
           Vendor2.dbo.Clubcard as cc
           on (i.id_number collate Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS) = cc.ClubCardId
      where i.id_code = 'PS'
     ) c
where minmik <> maxmik;
```

This calculates the minimum and maximum `MemberInternalKey` for each `customer_code`.  The outer `where` then returns only rows where these are different.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
Declare @YourTable table (customer_code int, id_number int, MemberInternalKey int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(5549032,4000,4926877),
(5549032,4001,4926877),
(5031101,4007,2379218),
(2831779,4029,1763760),
(2831779,4062,4950922)

Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Join (
        Select customer_code
         From  @YourTable
         Group By customer_code
         Having min(MemberInternalKey)<>max(MemberInternalKey)
      ) B on A.customer_code=B.customer_code
```

Returns

```
customer_code   id_number   MemberInternalKey
2831779         4029        1763760
2831779         4062        4950922
```